# Inconsistent behaviour with browserstack testing of ReactJS via travis-ci vs localhost

Tags: jasmine, reactjs, karma-runner, travis-ci, browserstack

I'm running test towards browserstack with karma (karma-browserstack-launcher, browserify + reactify), using jasmine as test suite with my reactjs code, and I'm getting inconsistent behaviour.

If I run karma start karma.conf from my laptop (using `Chrome 39 on windows 8.1`), every test runs fine, but if I the command is run on travis-ci (via npm test), I get several exceptions, from missing objects to `Error: Invariant Violation: findComponentRoot`-errors from react. (The stacktrace from this error gives me no good lead on where to fix this)

I'm getting basically the same results if I use `Firefox 35 on MAX OS X 10.10` and `Firefox 35 on Windows 8.1`, except from the `Error: Invariant Violation: findComponentRoot`-error from react.

If I run the tests with `Firefox 35 on Windows 8.1` locally, the whole test blow up with the error `ReferenceError: require is not defined` from all the test-files.

What could be wrong here? Is there any reported inconsistency like this?

I'm not even sure where to report this error, since there's several players on the field (karma, browserstack, travis, jasmine, react).

Comment: When using the JSX compiler I've noticed problems with null references not yet instantiated, when I run outside of the JSX compiler they seem to go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was a blunder from my side. I forgot that when Travis CI initialize the job, it always installs the latest npm modules. I reinstalled the npm modules locally and got the same behaviour on both ends. Hope this will help someone else with the same issue :)